# What do you get when you melt and solidify sand?

Tags: minerals

Would you get something brittle like glass or something like granite?

Comment: More like glass, I guess.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Why?

Comment: Just my gut feeling.

Comment: There are many different types and definitions of both sand and glass.  See the entries in the respective Wikipedia pages (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sand and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass).  This should either help you more clearly state what you are asking or maybe even answer your question.

Comment: Where I live the sand is eroded granite. The key issue is how quickly you cool the melt. Slow it can crystallize, fast it can be glass.

Comment: Well, it depends on the sand. At White Sands National Monument the sand is gypsum. The black sand beaches on Oahu are basalt particles. // Typical sand is mostly quartz particles. Lighting can fuse the sand into a silica glass called fulgurite. Trinitite is the glassy residue left on the desert floor after the plutonium-based Trinity nuclear bomb test.

Comment: Look at fulgurites for some examples. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulgurite